# Filtering specific numbers from a .txt file with C#

Tags: c#, text, autocad

I have been trying to mess around with the AutoCAD LT command line in the hopes of linking it with a C# program. I've focused on the command line because there are steep limitations when it comes to coding for LT releases. In my quest I figured out how to record commands into a log file (saved as a .txt file).

The log file:

```
Command: _dimlinear 
Specify first extension line origin or select object:
Specify second extension line origin:
Specify dimension line location or
[Mtext/Text/Angle/Horizontal/Vertical/Rotated]:
Dimension text = 712.75
Command: DIMLINEAR
Specify first extension line origin or <select object>: 
Specify second extension line origin: 
Specify dimension line location or 
[Mtext/Text/Angle/Horizontal/Vertical/Rotated]: 
Dimension text = 628.70
```

I am trying to only extract the numbers in the lines starting with "Dimension text = ". How do I achieve this using C#?

Comment: Please try it first and then when you are stuck you can find help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with Linq and Regex.

```
var array = str.Split(new []{Environment.NewLine},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var regex = new Regex(@"(Dimension)\s+(text)\s+(=)\s+(?<Value>([+-]?(\d*\.)?\d+)+)",RegexOptions.Compiled);
var resultArray =  from entry in array
                let match = regex.Match(entry)
                where match.Success                
                select decimal.Parse(match.Groups["Value"].Value);
```

Output for the given example in OP

```
712.75 
628.70
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo("FILE LOCATION");
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader( fi.ToString() );
        String Line = "";
        while ( ( Line = reader.ReadLine() ) != null )
        {
            if ( !Line.Contains("Dimension text") {
                continue;
            }
            String Property = Line.Split( '=' )[0];
            String Value = Line.Substring( Property.Length + 1, Line.Length - Property.Length - 1 );
            Console.WriteLine( Value ); // This line will print value of Dimension text
        }
```

hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [File.ReadLines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readlines?view=netframework-4.7.2) and LINQ to query the file and split the lines you're interested in, to select the dimensions. I'm not sure how it'll perform if the file is huge, but it should work pretty well.

```
var logFile = File.ReadLines("your_file_path")

var dimensions = (from entry in logFile
                  where entry.StartsWith("Dimension text")
                  let parts = entry.Split(' ')
                  select decimal.Parse(parts.Last())).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Regular Expressions.

```
var input = @"Command: _dimlinear 
Specify first extension line origin or select object:
Specify second extension line origin:
Specify dimension line location or
[Mtext/Text/Angle/Horizontal/Vertical/Rotated]:
Dimension text = 712.75
Command: DIMLINEAR
Specify first extension line origin or <select object>: 
Specify second extension line origin: 
Specify dimension line location or 
[Mtext/Text/Angle/Horizontal/Vertical/Rotated]: 
Dimension text = 628.70
Dimension text = 628";
            var regex = new Regex( @"Dimension text = (\d+(\.\d*)?)" );
            foreach( Match match in regex.Matches( input ) ) {
                var num = decimal.Parse( match.Groups[ 1 ].Value );
                Console.WriteLine( "Num: " + num );
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a tiny change to the answer posted by @AnuViswan, to get every entry:

```
string str = richTextBox1.Text;
        var array = str.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        var regex = new Regex(@"(?<Value>([+-]?(\d*\.)?\d+)+)", RegexOptions.Compiled);
        MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(str);
        foreach (Match la in matches)
        {
            Console.writeLine(la);
        }
```